# Unable to fix length issues when the content is present

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I've created a vba script to parse some links out of a table from a webpage. The ID I've used within my script to reach the table is dynamic and I like to stick to this way. The script is doing fine at this moment if I go for my first approach. But, I do not want to use this same line `Html.querySelectorAll("#DataTables_Table_0 tbody tr")` twice so I rectified my first script to be like the second one.

> But the second approach spits out this error `Invalid use of Null` pointing at this line `For i = 0 To elem.Length - 1` whereas my first script is still using the length to get the content.

My current approach: ***(working one)***

```
Sub GetCardLinks()
    Const timeLimit& = 10
    Const baseUrl = "https://www.psacard.com"
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer, Html As HTMLDocument
    Dim R&, T As Double, elem As Object

    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://www.psacard.com/psasetregistry/baseball/company-sets/16"
        While .Busy = True Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        Set Html = .document
        T = Timer

        Do
            Set elem = Html.querySelectorAll("#DataTables_Table_0 tbody tr")
            If Timer - T > timeLimit Then Exit Do
            DoEvents
        Loop While elem.Length = 0

        With Html.querySelectorAll("#DataTables_Table_0 tbody tr")
            For i = 0 To .Length - 1
                R = R + 1: Sheets(1).Cells(R, 1) = .Item(i).querySelector("td a[href^='/psasetregistry/baseball/company-sets/']").getAttribute("href")
            Next i
        End With
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

My second approach: ***(I do not want to use this `Html.querySelectorAll("#DataTables_Table_0 tbody tr")` twice)***

```
Sub GetCardLinks()
    Const baseUrl = "https://www.psacard.com"
    Const timeLimit& = 10
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer, Html As HTMLDocument
    Dim R&, T As Date, elem As Object

    With IE
        .Visible = False
        .navigate "https://www.psacard.com/psasetregistry/baseball/company-sets/16"
        While .Busy = True Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        Set Html = .document
        T = Timer

        Do
            Set elem = Html.querySelectorAll("#DataTables_Table_0 tbody tr")
            If Timer - T > timeLimit Then Exit Do
            DoEvents
        Loop While elem.Length = 0

        For i = 0 To elem.Length - 1
            R = R + 1: ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(R, 1) = elem.Item(i).querySelector("td a[href^='/psasetregistry/baseball/company-sets/']").getAttribute("href")
        Next i
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

***What possible change should I bring about to make my second approach work?***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't set to html variable. Work off the .document

```
Option Explicit

Sub GetCardLinks()
    Const baseUrl = "https://www.psacard.com"
    Const timeLimit& = 10
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer, Html As HTMLDocument
    Dim R&, T As Date, elem As Object, i As Long

    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://www.psacard.com/psasetregistry/baseball/company-sets/16"
        While .Busy = True Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        T = Timer
        Do
            Set elem = .document.querySelectorAll("#DataTables_Table_0 tbody tr")
            If Timer - T > timeLimit Then Exit Do
            DoEvents
        Loop While elem.Length = 0

        For i = 0 To elem.Length - 1
            R = R + 1: ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(R, 1) = elem.item(i).querySelector("td a[href^='/psasetregistry/baseball/company-sets/']").getAttribute("href")
        Next i
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Yeah, it is working @QHarr. But what's wrong with the usage of html variable in this case?

Comment: you have already set it into a variable so your loop has no effect. It will always return null as doesn't update during a timed loop.